# How can you find all parameter estimates are statistically significant but without performing any sophisticated calculations?

Tags: econometrics, regression

I have a question that contains a list of parameter estimates and their related standard errors. It then goes on to ask that I explain how I know all parameter estimates are statistically significant at a 5% significance level, but without performing any 'sophisticated calculations'. Does this mean I have to compare the standard errors to the estimators or do I find their t-values?

Answer (score 3):

Normally an exam question like that can be solved by simply calculating the $t$-statistics which can be simply done as:

$$t_{\hat{\beta}} = \frac{\hat{\beta}-\beta_0}{se(\hat{\beta})}$$

where $\hat{\beta}$ is the estimate, $\beta_0$ is the assumed value of beta under null (usually 0) and $se(\hat{\beta})$ standard error of the coefficient and then compare it to $5\%$ critical value (for large $n$ and two sided hypothesis approximately $1.96$).

However, you should ask your teacher/supervisor to clarify what is considered 'sophisticated calculation' - some might consider even subtraction and division sophisticated. An approximate rule of thumb that requires even less calculation is to see if the coefficient $\hat{\beta}$ (and assuming null hypothesis assumes $\beta_0=0$) is twice as large as the standard error.